# Looking for a build activity which breaks a build when new warnings are introduced

Tags: tfs, code-coverage, tfsbuild, custom-action

We're attempting to clean up a big bunch of brown field code, while at the same time a team is adding new functionality. We'd like to make sure changed and new code is cleaned from any compiler/code analysis or other warnings, but there's too many of them to begin  by cleaning up the current solution.

We're using TFS 2010.

So the following was proposed:

- Write/select a build activity which compares the list of warnings in the build against the lines of code that changed with that check-in.
- If the warning provides a line number, and that line number was changed, fail the build.

I understand this will not find all new warnings and things introduced in other parts of the code will not be flagged, but it's at least something.

Another option that was  proposed:

- Compare the list of warnings of the previous known good build against the list of this build. If there are new warnings (track on file name level), fail the build.

Any known Actions out there that might provide said functionality?

Any similar Actions that can act on Code Coverage reports?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We're using TFS 2010, updated above

Comment: This looks like a great feature request for the Community TFS Build Extensions CodePlex project:  http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanx Ed :) Have any time on hands ;)

Comment: Added: http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/discussions/347749

Comment: For "code analysis": Run it on everything and add all current errors/warnings to GlobalSuppression files. The suppressions are tied to line numbers so you will only see code analysis warnings as you add new/edit old code.

Comment: Somewhat strict, but you can pass `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=True` to MSBuild after suppressing all current warnings in GlobalSuppression

Comment: That's all good an dandy if you only have CA warnings. We already use 2 different sets of rules, one for projects that have been cleaned, one for dirty projects. We still want to ensure dirty projects won't get any dirtier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This following activity is just a basic approach, that returns `false` if your current build has less or equal warnings than your last build and `true` if they have risen.
Another activity that can locate *new* warnings and/or present with their location in code would clearly be superior, yet I thought this might be an interesting startpoint:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;

namespace CheckWarnings
{
    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public sealed class CheckWarnings : CodeActivity<bool>
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<IBuildDetail> CurrentBuild { get; set; }  //buildDetail
        public InArgument<string> Configuration { get; set; }       //platformConfiguration.Configuration
        public InArgument<string> Platform { get; set; }            //platformConfiguration.Platform


        protected override bool Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            IBuildDetail currentBuildDetail = context.GetValue(CurrentBuild);
            string currentConfiguration = context.GetValue(Configuration);
            string currentPlatform = context.GetValue(Platform);

            Uri lastKnownGoodBuildUri = currentBuildDetail.BuildDefinition.LastGoodBuildUri;
            IBuildDetail lastKnownGoodBuild = currentBuildDetail.BuildServer.GetBuild(lastKnownGoodBuildUri);

            int numOfCurrentWarnings = GetNumberOfWarnings(currentBuildDetail, currentConfiguration, currentPlatform);
            context.TrackBuildMessage("Current compile presents " + numOfCurrentWarnings + " warnings.", BuildMessageImportance.Normal);

            int numOfLastGoodBuildWarnings = GetNumberOfWarnings(lastKnownGoodBuild, currentConfiguration,
                                                                 currentPlatform);
            context.TrackBuildMessage("Equivalent last good build compile presents " + numOfLastGoodBuildWarnings + " warnings.", BuildMessageImportance.Normal);

            if (numOfLastGoodBuildWarnings < numOfCurrentWarnings)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static int GetNumberOfWarnings(IBuildDetail buildDetail, string configuration, string platform)
        {
            var buildInformationNodes =
                buildDetail.Information.GetNodesByType("ConfigurationSummary");

            foreach (var buildInformationNode in buildInformationNodes)
            {
                string localPlatform, numOfWarnings;
                string localConfiguration = localPlatform = numOfWarnings = "";
                foreach (var field in buildInformationNode.Fields)
                {

                    if (field.Key == "Flavor")
                    {
                        localConfiguration = field.Value;
                    }
                    if (field.Key == "Platform")
                    {
                        localPlatform = field.Value;
                    }
                    if (field.Key == "TotalCompilationWarnings")
                    {
                        numOfWarnings = field.Value;
                    }
                }
                if(localConfiguration == configuration && localPlatform == platform)
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32((numOfWarnings));
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this activity doesn't provide with exception handling and should further be refined, in case your build definitions build more than one solutions.
It takes three input args (`buildDetail`, `platformConfiguration.Configuration` and `platformConfiguration.Platform`) and should be placed directly after the `Run MSBuild` activity.

Comment: I'll come back with an updated version once I find time for it :)